# Global variable vs passing same variable through multiple functions

Tags: c++

What is considered the best practice to use? Passing the same argument through multi-layered functions or declaring global variables inside a class. In terms of performance, what's better?

Is there a different approach I can take?

Passing the same argument through multi-layered functions:

```
Class MyClass() {
    public:
        funcA(int averages, bool debug);

    private:
        funcB(bool debug);
        funcC(int averages, bool debug);
        funcD(int averages);
};

void funcA(int averages, bool debug) {
    funcB(debug);
    // do stuff
    if (debug)
        // print stuff
    funcC(averages, debug);
}

void funcB(bool debug) {
    // do stuff
    if (debug)
        //print stuff
}

void funcC (int averages, bool debug) {
    // do stuff  
    funcD (averages);
    if (debug)
        //print stuff
}

funcD (int averages) {
    // do something w/ averages
}
```

Declaring global variables inside class:

```
Class MyClass() {
    public:
        funcA(int averages, bool debug);

    private:
        int m_averages;
        bool m_debug;

        funcB();
        funcC();
        funcD();
};

void funcA(int averages, bool debug) {
    m_averages = averages;
    m_debug = debug;

    funcB();
    // do stuff
    if (debug)
        // print stuff
    funcC();
}

void funcB() {
    // do stuff
    if (m_debug)
        //print stuff
}

void funcC () {
    // do stuff  
    funcD ();
    if (m_debug)
        //print stuff
}

funcD () {
    // do something w/ m_averages
}
```

Comment: Pass the variable as a parameter. The fact that it goes through 23 parameter list doesn't matter -- the fact that it prevents namespace collisions does. The use of globals for performance reasons ceased in the late '80s. There is no penalty for using the calling convention for your architecture.

Comment: _Declaring global variables inside class_ A variable defined inside a class is not a global variable.  It is a member variable.  They are very different things.  And a member variable might be a suitable choice here, depending on how many functions need to test it.

Comment: Note that the member variables are passed to every method via a pointer to the class instance (as a hidden first argument to the method). So member variables are likely more efficient than individual parameters.

Comment: Depends a lot on what you are going to do with this debug flag. If the same instance of `MyClass` can be simultaneously used with and without debugging enabled, then debug is not object state and should not be a member. If debug is set for an object, stays set, and all users of the instance get debugging, that's a valid class member. I'd go a step further and say in the latter case that debug should not be set as an argument to `funcA`, it should have a setter or be an argument to the constructor.